# Не правильная работа модального окна

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Без лишних слов,не смотря на то,что модальному окну дан `z-index: 1000` что больше чем у блока `photos`,если навести мышку туда,где располагается текст,внутри блоков `pic`,то сработает анимация при наведении,что примечательно,она сработает только тогда,когда наведении именно на текст,если просто на блок,то все работает как надо,анимация не срабатывает. Вот картинка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body{
    margin : 0;
}

/* modWin */

.modWin{
    width: 100 %;
    height: 100 %;

    display: flex;
    justify - content: center;
    align - items: center;

    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    z - index: 1000;

    position: fixed;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
}

.modWin.win{
    width: 85 %;
    height: 85 %;

    display: flex;
    justify - content: center;
    align - items: center;

    background: #fff;
    border - radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z - index: 1000;
}

.modWin.win video{
    max - width: 75 %;
    min - height: 75 %;

    border - radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
}

.modWin.win button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}

/* photos */

.photos{
    width: 90 %;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0;

    display: flex;
    flex - wrap: wrap;
    justify - content: space - between;
}

.pic{
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    margin - bottom: 30px;

    display: flex;
    justify - content: center;
    align - items: center;

    background: url('../video_bg1.jpg');
    background - repeat: no - repeat;
    background - position: 0 0;
    background - size: cover;

    border - radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;

    transition: all .2s;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pic:nth - child(2) {
background: url("../video_bg2.jpg");
    background - size: cover;
}

.pic : nth - child(3) {
background: url("../video_bg3.jpg");
    background - size: cover;
}

.pic : nth - child(4) {
background: url("../video_bg4.jpg");
    background - size: cover;
}

.pic::after{
    content: "";

    width: 100 %;
    height: 100 %;

    background: #000;
    opacity: .6;
    transition: all .2s;

    position: absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
}

.pic p{
    opacity : 0;

    color: #fff;
    font - family: sans - serif;
    font - weight: 700;
    font - size: 20px;
    z - index: 1000;

    transition: all .2s;;
}

.pic:hover::after{
    opacity: .8;
}

.pic : hover p{
    opacity : 1;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="modWin">
  <div class="win">
   <video src="" controls></video>
   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Close</button>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="photos">
  <div class="pic" src="video_bg1.jpg">
   <p>Mr.Robot</p>
  </div>

  <div class="pic" src="video_bg2.jpg">
   <p>Game of thrones</p>
  </div>

  <div class="pic" src="video_bg3.jpg">
   <p>Walking dead</p>
  </div>

  <div class="pic" src="video_bg4.jpg">
   <p>Fight club</p>
  </div>
 </div>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так у вам у класса `.pic p` тоже `z-index: 1000;`. А так как эти элементы по DOM-дереву располагаются ниже модального окна, их слои будут выше. Дайте модальному окну `z-index: 1010;` хотя бы.

Comment: Либо, можно попробовать воспользоваться контекстами и задать для класса `photos` свойство `z-index: 1;`. Тогда любое содержимое тега с классом `photos` должно быть ниже модального окна. Но это в теории.

Comment: Тьфу ты,хотел поставить для '''.pic p``` ```z-index: 1```,т.к без этого он был бы под ```:after``` и был бы серым,а на автомате поставил 1000 вместо 1:).Спасибо